# How can you get API test results from blazemeter

Tags: api, selenium, automated-tests, blazemeter

Hi I'm an intern and i have an assignment in Blaze Merter online tool.
I have set up a functional GUI test and a schedule where the test will be executed and we need to retrieve API results from those tests using a script or something like that so that we could send out the results via email and SMS. The results that are sent by the Blazemeter aren't good because they send you only the link for the test.